# Make a Self-Learning Custom ner model in Spacy

Tags: model, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I have made a Custom ner spacy model . Although as it is work my specific stock market sector, Accuracy of the model is very poor. And training of the model requires around 1.5 Hours

Is their any way where i can daily add few datasets to my model , So that it keeps on learning . Cause otherwise its just a static ner model ?

Comment: You can add datasets, but you need to get them or create them.

Comment: Yes , I will update that dataset everyday. Is their any way forward afterthat ?